# Eclipse Error ClassNotFoundException error on every project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I am new to eclipse, Java and Android development. I have spent the majority of the past week working with de-compiling several .apk's to look at source code for popular apps. When I attempt to run the programs with the emulator in Eclipse I get the following error on every single project. I started a new project following a tutorial in a book thinking something was corrupt when de-compiling and the same problem persists...

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.linearlayout/com.linearlayout.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.linearlayout.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList
[[zip file "/data/app/com.linearlayout-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app-lib/com.linearlayout-1, /system/lib]]
```

I have looked at every single hit on Google searches and done each of the recommended fixes to no avail. 
**I have already done the following...**

```
Cleaning and rebuilding the projects.
Properties and adjusted settings in 'Java Build Path'
Added the .jar to the build path.
```

I cant seem to correct this error and I feel its something simple I'm overlooking.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks for you time.

-Kyle